# Regex breaking with preceding characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a phone number from a group of strings by compiling this regex:

```
exp = re.compile(r'(\+\d|)(([^0-9\s]|)\d\d\d([^0-9\s]|)([^0-9\s]|)\d+([^0-9\s]|)\d+)')
```

This successfully matches with a line like "+1(123)-456-7890". However, if I add anything in front of it, like "P: +1(123)-456-7890" it does not match. I tested on Regex websites but can't figure this out at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `re.search` (which scans) instead of `re.match`, which only looks at the beginning of the string. You could instead add a `.*` to the start.

Comment: Thank you - this was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will return following results

```
[('+1', '(123)-456-7890', '(', ')', '-', '-')]
```

If format is fixed you can use something like

```
phone = re.compile(r"\+\d\(\d+\)-\d+-\d+")
```

\d - matches digit.
+ - one or more occurrences.
\+ - for matching "+"
\( - for matching "("

```
str = "P: +1(123)-456-7890"
phone.findall(str)
```

Output :

```
['+1(123)-456-7890']
```